# Add Delay Time Admob Interstitial on Gameover

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, timedelay

I am new in C#, anyone can help me solving this. I am creating game in Unity and have integrated admob (interstitial) in Gameover state. Now it works well, however it looks much annoying for showing insterstitial ads everytime user reach the gameover screen. So here I think it's good to add some delay time within the ads showing. As far I got some simple logic but it doesn't work as I need, not sure.

Here is my code, for example I want it to have 2 minutes delay, so at gameover it won't execute the interstitial ads if it doesn't reach the delay time. The counter should keep counting continously. If the counter reach more 2 minutes and the next gameover screen appear, the ads should show up and the counter restarting counting from zero.

```
// For timer Admob
public int counter = 0;
public bool timer = true;

void Update()
{

    if (timer == true)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

And in my gameover screen

```
if (counter >= 120) // delay for 2 minutes
{
    <<my custom code to show admob>>
    timer = true;
    counter = 0;// set the counter to zero and restarting count
}
else
{
    timer = true; // it will keep counting
}
```

Really apreciated for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Update()` is called every frame (probably around 30 - 60 times per second) so delay need to be much higher, also to make your game not frame dependant use `Time.deltaTime`.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

Edit: Also in shown code, to `timer` variable you are never assigning `false` so looks like it's redundant. You're comparing variable `delayAdmob` in an if statement, but where do you change or declare it?

Comment: whoopss... sorry edited!
I am still learning c# unity, not sure how to use deltatime. I think the counter++ don't work because I put it in wrong place. I don't know where it shoud placed.

Comment: @MasNino Try increasing delay (120 in gameover screen) to something like 3600 and it should be around 2 minutes i think. Also you didn't state what is your problem now. Ad is not showing at all? Or it's the same like without that script?

Comment: @MasNino or instead you can use `counter += Time.deltaTime`. But I can't test it right now.

Comment: now it return error "Cannot implicitly convert type `float' to `int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)", but at least I know something. The counter work, but it should fix :)

Comment: Change int to float at counter and add counter += Time.deltaTime * 1 ,now it work great! Thanks swistak